# How can I filter JSON listview

Tags: android, arrays, json, objectlistview

What I want is to show in the list is the String that `equals(London)` in:

```
String location =  respons.getString("location");
```

if it equals to Manchester, I don't want it to be in the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject respons =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);  
    String id = respons.getString("id");
    String location =  respons.getString("location");
    String info = respons.getString("name");
    String img = respons.getString("img");

    listitmes.add(new Listitme(id, location, info, img));
    listAllItme();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject respons =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
// do your test hire if respons.getString("location") equlas the String "manchestar"
if(respons.getString("location").equlas("manchestar")){
    String id=respons.getString("id");
    String info=respons.getString("name");
    String img=respons.getString("img");
    listitmes.add(new Listitme(id,location,info,img));
    listAllItme();
}
```